# jQuery #tracking API not working with jquery html code

Tags: jquery

jQuery #tracking API not working with jquery html code.

Here is the Tracking code.

```
var awb = jQuery('#tracking-form-input-code').val();
var url = "http://app.ship-now.ae/track?AWB=" + awb
```

---

**Edit** snippet with above code and implied HTML

```js
var awb = jQuery('#tracking-form-input-code').val();
var url = "http://app.ship-now.ae/track?AWB=" + awb

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='tracking-form-input-code' value='xxx'>
```

Comment: how are you calling this url, what value you are getting in awb?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   In your question, please provide enough *context* to allow us to see the issue; specifically the HTML that matches your id.   Do you get an errors in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: I've added a snippet with some **implied** HTML and your javascript works fine - it's likely an issue with either *when* you run your code or an issue with the HTML (eg **misspelt ID** or **matching id not an input**).   Please [edit] and update the snippet to provide enough code to *demonstrate* the issue.

Comment: What's "not working" exactly?

Comment: *Look at the url it's not working* - it's working fine in the snippet.  Are you looking at a different "url" from us?

Comment: jQuery is not reactivity. You need listening to event`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#tracking-form-input-code").change(function(){
    var awb = this.value;
 var url = "http://app.ship-now.ae/track?AWB=" + awb
 console.log(url);
  });
});`

Comment: This is my tracking pls check my jquery code and give me final code of working. https://www.ship-now.ae/our-tracking/

Comment: Site is blocked. See [mcve] and try to reproduce the issue in the snippet ([edit]).